# use async call to webservice when you are not interested in the response

Tags: wcf

I use a call to a webservice in order to wake up a process which processes some images.
The process takes 10minutes,so I don't want the asp.net client waiting for that.

What I did was a simple call async to the service to start the processing.

But it looks like ConvertToCubeService service doesn't bother to start.
ConvertToCubeService is a workflow service. I call it from within the activity of another workflow service.
I am sure that the code reaces the async call to ConvertToCubeService .

```
public sealed class CallProcessingAsync : CodeActivity
{
    // Define an activity input argument of type string
    public InArgument<string> EquirectangularImagePath { get; set; }
    public InArgument<string> SaveImageDirectoryPath { get; set; }
    public InArgument<string> ImageName { get; set; }
    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
        ConvertToCubeService.ServiceClient client = new ConvertToCubeService.ServiceClient();
        ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFaces param = new ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFaces();

        var apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;


        param.EquirectangularFilePath=apPath+context.GetValue(this.EquirectangularImagePath);
        param.imageName = context.GetValue(this.ImageName);
        param.SaveCubicFacesDirectory = apPath + context.GetValue(this.SaveImageDirectoryPath);
        client.ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted += new EventHandler<ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFacesCompletedEventArgs>(client_ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted);
        client.ConvertToCubeFacesAsync(param);//call async the server to do the work
        using (var db = new panonestEntities())
        {
            var p = db.Panoramas.Where(x => x.ImageName.Equals(param.imageName)).First();
            p.Status = "Called processing. wait";
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    void client_ConvertToCubeFacesCompleted(object sender, ConvertToCubeService.ConvertToCubeFacesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new panonestEntities())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run something that takes 10 minutes on your web server. You should write a windows service for that. You could have a simple webservice that puts a record into a table to trigger the windows service to do its work
.

Comment: actually the web server is implemented as a Windows workflow service. So I think it does something similar to that. but the problem is that I call the async method and the service does not start..

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. You may want to provide information about how you are trying to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way would be not to do the async stuff client side but server side because when you ignore the response, you won't know if the call even has reached the server.

I would wirte the server operation in that way, that it starts the long running task asynchronous and then returns quickly.

The client can wait on the call and can be sure, that the call arrived at the server successfully and the operation was started.

Comment: the asyncronous call to the service is done from within the CodeActivity of another Workflow service. So actually I have one service calling another, just to wake it up. This is why I use Async call, because i'm not interested in the return value of ConvertToCubeService service

Comment: Yes, i understand. But when calling a service you have two kinds of return value: 1) The information, that the call was transmitted sucessfully and reached the server and 2) The actual return value of the operation. I say its better to wait for the first which you can get, when you use the async pattern server side.